# Compiling Typescript for Visual Studio Code extension gets many errors related to generics

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

This extension was compiling fine. Not sure what has changed, but now when I run

node ./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc -p ./src

I see many errors like the following:

node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.d.ts(1378,151): error TS2314: Generic type 'Promise' requires 2 type argument(s)

From what little I have been able to find, this may be caused by two different interface definitions being combined mistakenly, but I don't see where two definitions are being included.